# Sort arraylist with selectionsort via Array

Tags: java

I just finished a Course in programming and was asked to do a sorting algorithm, so I made a selection sort algorithm for an arraylist, however after the course my teacher said that I should've used Arrays for sorting? The list I was tryna sort was constantly growing so I thought I couldnt use arrays? Does anyone know what he meant? Here's the sorting method anyways.

```java
    private void sortBids() {

            for (int i = 0; i < bids.size() - 1; i++)
            {
                for (int j = i + 1; j < bids.size(); j++)
                {
                    if (bids.get(i).getAmount() > bids.get(j).getAmount()) {

                        Bid temp = bids.get(j);
                        bids.set(j, bids.get(i));
                        bids.set(i, temp);
                    }
                }
            }


}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "constantly growing"? I think your professor simply wanted you to avoid using complex data structures, like lists

Comment: the implementation is incorrect

Comment: @mangusta, well, it looks like a correct implementation, but of a different sorting algorithm:)

Comment: @dyukha resembles bubblesort with even worse locality

Comment: @mangusta It *is* a selection sort, it just moves all smaller values to the front, instead of first locating the smallest value and moving it, so it's a less efficient selection sort. The effect is still that it moves smallest of remaining values to index `i`.

Comment: @skyy6 For the purpose of the sort, the list isn't growing, so sorting an array is  very valid. He likely simply meant to that you should start simple, i.e. using an array is "simpler" than using a `List`, again for the purpose of the sort.

Comment: @WJS It is not a bubblesort. Bubblesort compares neighboring values. This code doesn't. It's a selection sort, just like OP said.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a correct implementation of [Selection Sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_sort). `swap` method takes (`O(1)` for arrays, so it doesn't affect the result).

I can see this is not an array; it looks like a collection (`List`). For arrays it could look like this:

```
private void sortBids(Bid[] bids) {
    for (int i = 0; i < bids.length - 1; i++)
        for (int j = i + 1; j < bids.length; j++)
            if (bids[i].getAmount() > bids[j].getAmount())
                swap(bids, i, j);
}

private static void swap(Bid[] bids, int i, int j) {
    Bid bid = bids[i];
    bids[i] = bids[j];
    bids[j] = bid;
}
```

But in general case for `List` this is not correct, because it could be very ineffective (e.g. for `LinkedList`); but for `ArrayList` it's acceptable because it's like an array.

If you have a collection you have to write a `Comparator`. This is trivial for your case:

```
Comparator<Bid> SORT_BY_AMOUNT_ASC = Comparator.comparingInt(Bid::getAmount);
```

So you're able to sort `List<Bid> bids`:

```
bids.sort(SORT_BY_AMOUNT_ASC);
```

And finally, you can use [PriorityQueue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Priority_queue). All you have to do in this case is just add all your elements into this queue and iterate over it:

```
Queue<Bid> queue = new PriorityQueue<>(SORT_BY_AMOUNT_ASC);
queue.addAll(...);

for(Bid bid : queue)
    // sorted bids
```